# ExtJS Ajax vs Extjs Store for single row from server

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

Scenario: I have a URL that returns details about the current logged in user. I.e.

- *one* record
- no list needed

Options I have:

1. Perform a manual [ExtJS Ajax call](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax) each time, having to insert the code everywhere I need the callbacks etc.
2. Create an [ExtJS Store](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) *once* and fetch the first record from the store instance every time.

Question: Any better options? I'm using ExtJS 4.1.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not answering your question directly, but I wouldn't recommend either ways - I have a similar system where I need to know the type of user, but I require to know it when some controllers are dynamically loaded (before application launch). I think the best way is to include include in your index.php a php file that outputs a javascript with a global variable containing the user information (have a look at direct - it does a similar thing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to go into low level details to do something like that; use the standard tools. Define a Model, assign it a Proxy of the type you need, and load it. See the docs: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model

Comment: this is the correct answer. Load the user once at startup, and on demand, if needed

Comment: @AlexanderTokarev Isn't each [`load`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-static-method-load) call an HTTP request? (Ajax or REST, depending on how the proxy is set up)

Comment: @Josvic Zammit Not necessarily. You can use Ext.Direct remoting instead of plain Ajax or REST, it supports request batching.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing an ajax call each time?

Do it once, and assign it as a global variable?

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'page.php',
    params: {
        id: 1
    },
    success: function(response){
        var text = response.responseText;
        window.user = Ext.JSON.decode(text);
        my.custom.launchFunction();//does your viewport etc for you
    }
});
```

Having done this, you can now, from **anywhere** do
`console.log(user.Name);`

Its neater, and faster, than doing a store lookup.

As a bonus, you user object can be much more complex than the store would handle without a ton of config.

Comment: Yes this is where I arrived so far. Can this call (to retrieve the `username`) be placed in a `utils` file? Where would that fit in ExtJS MVC architecture?

Comment: What I personally do is leave a css implementation of `loading` active, and then put this in my Ext.launch function ( eg I wont fire my viewport create function until this has returned a value ) I avoid JS mvc like the plague though, so my advice might not be correct here.

Comment: Yes, but you implication is that you are calling the ajax call each time you need to access your user object in the current page, if that is wrong, my answer has no real use.

Comment: Your answer has a use: it confirms that there isn't much to do at this stage. +1ed

Comment: I'm still confused as to how you are instantiating a store -once- and doing an ajax call -each time-. There is no real sense in doing a store once, if you need an active (updated) user object, or calling the ajax each time if you need a snapshot of the user as per the request event.

Comment: Getting the user info from the store would be a one liner; instead of the whole Ajax call. Server hits are not my concern in this case. "I avoid JS mvc like the plague though" ... why? I've recently started working with it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14864/discussion-between-alex-and-josvic-zammit)

Comment: This is my preferred method too. Why keep hitting the server for data that can be assigned to a global variable? Well done Josvic, but you must embrace MVC. The ExtJS framework will change your life :)

Comment: +1 for avoiding the use of Model and Store stuff for this simple singleton.

Comment: minus one for using global window object

Comment: @GeorgePligor This kind of use case is exactly what global objects are there for though. User gets called all over the place in complex applications, and implicitly having it in scope is awesome.